# Openlayers different colour shapes on one layer?

Tags: angular, openlayers

So I've written the code to allow me to add shapes to the map and the draw function looks like this

```
  addInteraction() {
    this.coreMap.map.addInteraction(this.modifyLayer);
    this.draw = new Draw({
      source: this.vectorSource,
      style: this.style,
      type: 'Point'
    });
    this.coreMap.map.addInteraction(this.draw);
    this.snap = new Snap({source: this.vectorSource});
    this.coreMap.map.addInteraction(this.snap);
  }
```

Which works fine lets me draw on the map ect, however if I try and change the style on the vectorLayer to lets say from a green point to a red one it will change every dot to red rather than the new ones, I've tried a couple of things;

- Tried pushing a new styles object into the vectorLayer.styles with setStyle([styleOneOpts, styleTwoOpts])
- Setting the style property of the Draw property to something different which will change the cursor to said colour but the drawn point will still be the vectorLayers style colour
- Tried creating a new Draw object and adding that as an entirely new interaction to the map

At the moment I'm presuming I'll have to create a new layer each time I want to create a new shape with a different colour, which is fine if there is no way around it but would prefer it to stay within one layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a style on each newly created feature, or alternatively set a color property on each feature for example `feature.set('color', 'red');` and use a style function for the layer.  This would use the color set on the feature, or default to black if none was set

```
style: function(feature) {
  return new Style({

    ...

      color: feature.get('color') || 'black',

   ...

  })
}
```